# Problems upolading files from local to server using scp

Tags: file-transfer, scp

I'm having problems in uploading some folders from the local machine to a server.
When I run the command

> `scp -r -i pathtokey.txt pathtomyfiles pathtotheserver`

For some folders the transfer doesn't succed. I noticed that this happens for the folders where I have R projects. It transfers just usually hidden files named as "source-pane.pper" "chunks.json", but nothing else.

For other folders, where I don't have any of that, the transfer goes fine, meaning that the command I'm using is ok.
Any suggestion of what is happening here and how to solve?

Just to give you all the information, my local machine has windows system

Thanks a lot,
Francesca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure why this is failing unfortunately. However an alternative may be to look at using rsync:

```
rsync <options> <source> <destination>
rsync -azv source_dir/ username@server:~/path/to/folder
```

I've not tried this while specifying an ssh key explicitly but the answer below explains how to do so. Alternatively you can just type in the password manually if you know it.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127352/specify-identity-file-id-rsa-with-rsync

Comment: This solution seems working, thanks.  It was a little tricky to use, since windows doesn't contain rsync but I was able to run it from the ubuntu windows app (I use it to run linux commands). Just to complete also what the link you posted says, if you run rsync from ubuntu app, you have to create and put the key in the home directory of the ubuntu partition and not in mnt/c/users... Only in this way you are able to change the permissions and make the key private.

Comment: Thanks for the update @francesca. It's been a while since I used a Windows device so I'd forgotten that `rsync` wasn't available! Glad you got it sorted :)